# Export Outlook 2010 professional calendar to excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook-2010

My version of Outlook (Professional 2010) does not have an import/export choice.  I can save it as an .ics .  Can I turn that file into an excel list ?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no option available to convert .ics to Excel list directly. For Outlook 2010, generally the Export option can be found via File > Options > Advanced > Export, there you can export the calendar to .csv file :

[image]